# Is the Integral of a Spline multiplied with the Exponential Function of the Spline solvable?

Tags: integration, spline

I want to compute the integral, I have borders for $x$, however I would like a function of y as the result:
$$
\int_a^b \quad \frac{\partial f(y,x)}{\partial y} \exp(f(y,x)) \quad dx
$$

$f(y,x)$ is a Tensor Product B-Spline.Hence:
$$
f(y,x) = \sum_a \sum_b B_a(y) B_b(x) \alpha_{a,b}
$$
The Derivatives and Integrals of the Basis $B$ exist, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline). See also the basis definition below:
$$
B_{i,0}(t) := \begin{cases}
 1 & \text{if } t_i \leq t < t_{i+1}, \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
$$
B_{i,p}(t) := \dfrac{t - t_i}{t_{i+p} - t_i} B_{i,p-1}(t) + \dfrac{t_{i+p+1} - t}{t_{i+p+1} - t_{i+1}} B_{i+1,p-1}(t)
$$
$$
\sum_i \alpha_i B_{i,k} = \sum_{i=r-k+2}^{s-1} k\frac{\alpha_i - \alpha_{i-1}}{t_{i+k} - t_i}B_{i,k-1} \quad \text{on} \quad [t_r, t_s]
$$

I wonder if there is not a trick (instead of using the product rule) since we have $f(y,x)$ both in $u$ and $v$.

Thanks in advance for any tip!